# Using while loop to get the right username from user

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, passwords

**I want to create a code which will ask the user its username and password.
The username and password will already be a variable.
This code will keep asking the user the username and password over and over again
until the right username and password are typed in.**
***However I am not able to create this code, please help.
Can anyone give me an example, please?***
I tried to create this code however, it doesn't work.First, if the username and the password are wrong the "Incorrect" just keeps repeating that's what I don't to happen and second I want that if the username or password is wrong the enter your username and enter your password keeps repeating until the user puts the credentials right.

```
answer_1 = ("america")
asnwer_2 = ("italy")
getin=input("Enter your Username: ")
getin_2=input("Enter your password :")
    if getin!=answer_1 or getin_2!=answer_2:
        print("Incorrect")
        continue
    print("Please proceed")
    break
```

Comment: Why not? What don't you understand?

Comment: You should provide more context in order to receive an answer.

Comment: If you show your work so far, and what's not working for you, people will be able to better answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
answer_1 = "america"
answer_2 = "italy"
getin_1 = input("Enter your Username: ")
getin_2 = input("Enter your password: ")

while getin_1 != answer_1 or getin_2 != answer_2:
    print("Incorrect")
    print("Please proceed")
    getin_1 = input("Enter your Username: ")
    getin_2 = input("Enter your password: ")

print("Your username and password are OK.")
```

To ask user again and again, you have to put question in a *loop* - `if` command is not sufficient.

There is no need to use `break` or `continue` commands as all required conditions are already in the `while` loop.

Comment: The code  is outputting incorrect an please proceed before the question is asked.Why?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SOURAVPREET\Desktop\Python GCSE YR 11\Testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    while getin_1 != answer_1 or getin_2 != answer_2:
NameError: name 'answer_2' is not defined    ***This is the error when i put the username and the password right***

Comment: Thanks, MATE, you saved me from failing my NEA.

Comment: Now there is just one thing, you know when i run my code, the phrase "incorrect "and "please proceed" pop up before the "enter your username" statement is there any way to fix that?

Comment: I fixed it in my answer now, so please copy / paste the code again.

Answer (score 1):

```
username = Bob
password = 123
user = ''
passw = ''

while username != user and password != passw: 
passw = input('Input password:')
user = input('Input username:')
```

Comment: There is another issue, if i type the username right and password is wrong the code works, however if the username is wrong but the password is right the code stops